# Simplify PHP Script for SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, str-replace, simplify

I'm a self-taught, beginner programmer. Recently I've been working on a PHP script to query a database with user-entered keywords. What I've come up with seems much more complicated than it needs to be, so I was wondering if there was a way I could simplify what I wrote. Please let me know if you have any other questions or need any more code. Thank you!

```
    $types = array();
    if(!empty($_GET['location_id']) && isset($_GET['location_id'])) $types[] = "groups.location_id = " . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['location_id']) . " ";
    if(!empty($_GET['season_id']) && isset($_GET['season_id'])) $types[] = "seasons.season_id = " . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['season_id']) . " ";
    if(!empty($_GET['event']) && isset($_GET['event'])) $types[] = "(`event` LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['event']) . "%' OR `note` LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['event']) . "%') ";
    if(!empty($_GET['place']) && isset($_GET['place'])) $types[] = "`place` LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['place']) . "%' ";
    if(!empty($_GET['city']) && isset($_GET['city'])) $types[] = "`city` LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['city']) . "%' ";
    if(!empty($_GET['state_abbr']) && isset($_GET['state_abbr'])) $types[] = "`state_abbr` LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['state_abbr']) . "%' ";
    if(!empty($_GET['weekday']) && isset($_GET['weekday'])) $types[] = "(`weekday` LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['weekday']) . "%' OR `through_weekday` LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['weekday']) . "%') ";
    if(!empty($_GET['month']) && isset($_GET['month'])) $types[] = "`month` LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['month']) . "%' ";
    if(!empty($_GET['day']) && isset($_GET['day'])) $types[] = "(`day` LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['day']) . "%' OR `through_day` LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['day']) . "%') ";
    if(!empty($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['year'])) $types[] = "`year` LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_GET['year']) . "%' ";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `WHERE` conditions are so different there wouldn't be any way of reducing the number of lines in the code but each line could be slightly shorter. Also you want to pass the submitted variables through [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

You can prepare all of your variables in a loop so you don't have to run through `mysql_real_escape` and `str_replace` on each line:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
  $_GET[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace(' ', '%', $val));
}
```

and I think the call to `isset()` is slightly redundant so after you've run the loop above each line could look something like this:

```
if (!empty($_GET['year'])) 
  $types[] = "`year` LIKE '%" . $_GET['year'] . "%' ";
```

Comment: I was just writing up a similar answer...only difference was I set an array with the used keys in `$_GET` and modified only those.  Probably don't want to scan and modify the entire `$_GET` since there may be other values he doesn't want to modify.

Comment: @AaronW. Could you show me what your code would look like? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.. It might make the code more clear and the sql writing a very easy job.

**Put this code for testing purposes:**

```
 $_GET['event']='jut for test';
 $_GET['place']='jut for test'; 
 $_GET['city']='jut for test'; 
 $_GET['state_abbr']='jut for test'; 
 $_GET['weekday']='jut for test'; 
 $_GET['month']='jut for test'; 
 $_GET['day']='jut for test';  
 $_GET['year']='jut for test';
```

**Then below that, put the actual code:**

```
$queryTmplArr=Array("(`@field` LIKE '%@value%' OR `note` LIKE '%@value%') ",
"`@field` LIKE '%@value%' ","`@field` LIKE '%@value%' ","`@field` LIKE '%@value%' ",
"(`@field` LIKE '%@value%' OR `through_weekday` LIKE '%@value%') ",
"`@field` LIKE '%@value%' ","(`@field` LIKE '%@value%' OR `through_day` LIKE '%@value%') ",
"`@field` LIKE '%@value%' ");

$i=0;
foreach($_GET as $key =>$rawData)
{
     $cleanData= mysql_real_escape_string( str_replace(' ', '%', $rawData) ) ;   
     $queryTmplArr[$i]=str_replace('@value', $cleanData, $queryTmplArr[$i]);
     $queryTmplArr[$i]=str_replace('@field', $key, $queryTmplArr[$i]);
     $i++;
}
```

**And for testing purpose again:**

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($queryTmplArr );
```

**This will output this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => (`event` LIKE '%jut%for%test%' OR `note` LIKE '%jut%for%test%') 
    [1] => `place` LIKE '%jut%for%test%' 
    [2] => `city` LIKE '%jut%for%test%' 
    [3] => `state_abbr` LIKE '%jut%for%test%' 
    [4] => (`weekday` LIKE '%jut%for%test%' OR `through_weekday` LIKE '%jut%for%test%') 
    [5] => `month` LIKE '%jut%for%test%' 
    [6] => (`day` LIKE '%jut%for%test%' OR `through_day` LIKE '%jut%for%test%') 
    [7] => `year` LIKE '%jut%for%test%' 
)
```

Is this okay?